# Setting height of sidebar to match container

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have a layout where the container holds a sidebar. I need the sidebar to be the exact same height as the container. Please see [this site](http://vitaminjdesign.com/mycity/) where the sidebar is `#leftbar` and the container is `#container`

If you look at the site, you will see what I mean. I either need a pure css solution or a jquery solution.

One important thing to keep in mind The nav is a vertical accordion, so when certain buttons are clicked, the sidebar, `#leftbar` will expand vertically. The solution needs to accommodate growth, so simply matching their heights using jquery isn't a viable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following properties to these elements:

```
#cotainer {
    position: relative
}

#leftbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#righthome {
    margin-left: 270px; /* looks to be about the width of the leftbar */
}
```

Giving the `#leftbar` the properties show, will ensure the top sticks to the top of the next parent element with `position: relative`, and the same for the bottom edge.

However this has a side effect. The `#righthome` element becomes the first thing in its parents box layout model, and therefore overlaps the left bar. To remedy this you give it a left margin to put it back in the place it would have been.